ошибка pytorch 'int' object has no attribute 'backward?
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torchvision.models import vgg19, VGG19_Weights

import copy
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.set_default_device(device)
# Какого размера изображение мы хотим обрабатывать
Insize = 256 if torch.cuda.is_available() else 128 #Если нет GPU делаем изображение поменьше

loader = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(Insize), #маштабируем
    transforms.CenterCrop(Insize), #обрезаем края
    transforms.ToTensor()]) # преобразуем в нужный класс

def image_loader(image_name):

    #загрузим и преобразуем картинку
    image = Image.open(image_name).convert('RGB')
    image = loader(image).unsqueeze(0)
    return image.to(device, torch.float)

style_img = image_loader("Screenshot_3.png")
content_img = image_loader("Screenshot_17.png")

assert style_img.size() == content_img.size()

unloader = transforms.ToPILImage()

plt.ion()

def imshow(tensor, title=None):
    image = tensor.cpu().clone()
    image = image.squeeze(0)
    image = unloader(image)
    plt.imshow(image)

    if title is not None:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.pause(0.001)

plt.figure()
imshow(style_img, title='Изображение"Стиль"')

plt.figure()
imshow(content_img, title='Изображение"Контент"')

class ContentLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, target,):
        super(ContentLoss, self).__init__()
        self.target = target.detach()

    def forward(self, input):
        self.loss = F.mse_loss(input, self.target)
        return input

def gram_matrix(input):
    a, b, c, d = input.size()
    features = input.view(a * b, c * d)
    G = torch.mm(features, features.t())
    return G.div(a * b * c * d)

class StyleLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, target_feature):
        super(StyleLoss, self).__init__()
        self.target = gram_matrix(target_feature).detach()

    def forward(self, input):
        G = gram_matrix(input)
        self.loss = F.mse_loss(G, self.target)
        return input

cnn = vgg19(weights=VGG19_Weights.DEFAULT).features.eval()

cnn_normalization_mean = torch.tensor([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
cnn_normalization_std = torch.tensor([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

#упоковочный класс
class Normalization(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, mean, std):
        super(Normalization, self).__init__()
        self.mean = torch.tensor(mean).view(-1, 1, 1)
        self.std = torch.tensor(std).view(-1, 1, 1)
    def forward(self, img):
        return (img - self.mean) / self.std

#название слоев, по которому бедем расчитывать рассхождение по контенту
content_layers_default = ['conv_4']
#название слоев, по которому бедем расчитывать рассхождение по стилю
style_layers_default = ['conv_1', 'conv_2', 'conv_3', 'conv_4', 'conv_5']

def get_style_model_and_losses(cnn, normalization_mean, normalization_std,
                               style_img, content_img,
                               content_layers=content_layers_default,
                               style_layers=style_layers_default):

#модуль чтобы нормализовать изображение
    normalization = Normalization(normalization_mean, normalization_std)
#будем складывать меры расхождениялоссы) в удобные массивы
    content_losses = []
    style_losses = []
# поскольку cnn является объектом типа nn.Sequential
# создадим новый nn.Sequential куда мы по порядку положим
# все модули, которые будут проводить вычисления в нейросети
    model = nn.Sequential(normalization)
    i = 0 #пройдемся по элементам в исходной нейросети и дадим им имена
    for layer in cnn.children():

       if isinstance(layer, nn.Conv2d):
            i += 1
            name = 'conv_{}'.format(i)
        elif isinstance(layer, nn.ReLU):
            name = 'relu_{}'.format(i)
            #чуть изменим параметры слоев активации
            # в исходной нейросети не работает с нашей реализацией сontent_losses и style_losses
            layer = nn.ReLU(inplace=False)
        elif isinstance(layer, nn.MaxPool2d):
            name = 'pool_{}'.format(i)
        elif isinstance(layer, nn.BatchNorm2d):
            name = 'bn_{}'.format(i)
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Unrecognized layer: {}'.format(layer.__class__.__name__))
#добавляем очередной модуль в нашу Sequential-модель
        model.add_module(name, layer)

    if name in content_layers:
        #а если к последнему слою нужно пристыковать контент-лосс, сделаем это
        target = model(content_img).detach()
        content_loss = ContentLoss(target)
        model.add_module("content_loss_{}".format(i), content_loss)
        content_losses.append(content_loss)

    if name in style_layers:
        #а если имя слоя в списке стиль-лоссов, добавим после  ннего соответсвующий лосс
        target_feature = model(style_img).detach()
        style_loss = StyleLoss(target_feature)
        model.add_module("style_loss_{}".format(i), style_loss)
        style_losses.append(style_loss)
#все слои которые идут после последнего добавленного контент лосса или стиль лосса
# нам будут не нужны, их можно отбросить
    for i in range(len(model) - 1, -1, -1):
        if isinstance(model[i], ContentLoss) or isinstance(model[i], StyleLoss):
            break
    model = model[:(i + 1)]
    return model, style_losses, content_losses

#чтобы использовать исходную картинку, раскоментируйте:
input_img = content_img.clone()

#чтобы использовать шум
#input_img = torch.randn(content_img.data.size())
# add the original input image to the figure:\n",
plt.figure()
imshow(input_img, title='Входное изображение')


def get_input_optimizer(input_img):
    optimizer = optim.LBFGS([input_img])
    return optimizer

def run_style_transfer(cnn, normalization_mean, normalization_std,
                      content_img, style_img, input_img, num_steps=300,
                      style_weight=10000, content_weight=100):
    print('Построение модели переноса стиля')
    model, style_losses, content_losses = get_style_model_and_losses(cnn,
                                                                    normalization_mean, normalization_std, style_img, content_img)

    input_img.requires_grad_(True)
    model.eval()
    model.requires_grad_(False)
    optimizer = get_input_optimizer(input_img)

    print('Оптимизируем картинку')
    run = [0]
    while run[0] <= num_steps:

        def closure():

            # скорректируем значение сходного изображения",
            with torch.no_grad():
                input_img.clamp_(0, 1)

            optimizer.zero_grad() # обнуляем градиенты
           model(input_img) # отправляем картинку в модель

            # посчитаем расхождение изображений по стилю и содержимому
            style_score = 0
            content_score = 0

            for sl in style_losses: style_score += sl.loss
            for cl in content_losses: content_score += cl.loss

            style_score *= style_weight # домножаем каждую компоновку лосса на заданный вес
            content_score *= content_weight

            loss = style_score + content_score
            # обратное значение распространения ошибки
            loss.backward()

            run[0] += 1
            if run[0] % 50 == 0:
                print("run {}:".format(run))
                print('Style Loss : {:4f} Content Loss: {:4f}'.format(
                    style_score.item(), content_score.item()))
                print()
            return style_score + content_score

        optimizer.step(closure)

    # ВОЗРАЩАЕМ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЕ
    with torch.no_grad():
        input_img.clamp_(0, 1)
    return input_img

output = run_style_transfer(cnn,
                    cnn_normalization_mean, cnn_normalization_std,
                    content_img, style_img, input_img)

plt.figure()
imshow(output, title = 'Полученное изображение')
#sphinx_gallery_thumbnail_number = 4
plt.ioff()
plt.show()


https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aaoTfxdB0RGEzjpFTlA_7xMCYOI-jJY9?usp=sharing

Где вы взяли этот код? Естественно, в loss у вас числовое значение, у него нет такой функции. Возможно вы имели в виду style_loss.backward(), но это не точно.
